# KeyPair size is wrong for ECDSA using BouncyCastle's API

Tags: bouncycastle, ecdsa

Am using BouncyCastle API to generate a signing Keypair which normally should be 32 bytes for privateKey size and 64 bytes for publicKey  size, but actually am getting 150 bytes privateKey size and 91 bytes for publicKey size ,the source code is like bellow :

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC"); 
org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec ecSpec=ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1"); keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

And even if I specify the domain params ( the recommended ones for NIST P-256 Curve ) the given result is also wrong, am I missing something ?

Comment: How are you computing the size?  Is it possible that you are computing the size of some DER-encoded data which contains padding and metadata instead of just computing the sizes of the actual elliptic curve data?

Comment: am calculating for example  the privateKey  byte array length : privateKey.getEncoded().length ;

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same promble.